# When I search developer name on Google Play not displaying my apps

Tags: android, google-play

my question is that when I try to search on Google Play for "gameimax" then it displays other developers apps so why it's not displaying only my apps with my developer name and displaying others apps with my apps?

Please help me with this. Is it possible that my competitors used my developer name in their keywords or any place to get listed with my search term?

Thanks,
Trisha,,,

Comment: You can have specific reference to your apps: https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Google+Inc.

Comment: Change developer name...

Comment: I don't understand what you want to say? can you describe more?

Comment: @TrishaThomas developer name also play roles in search. Change your developer name to unique. For example see this : https://play.google.com/store/search?q=Jetly%2BBrevo&c=apps

Comment: that's good but My brand name is "gameimax" then why it didn't display only my apps? that things I didn't understand.

Comment: See [google displays so many results](https://www.google.co.in/search?hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=gameimax&oq=gameimax&gs_l=hp.3...624473.624473.0.624642.1.1.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c..29.psy-ab..1.0.0.WDJbaWFW4II&pbx=1&biw=1375&bih=777&dpr=1&cad=cbv&sei=s5xrUs6hEcKHrQeh94HQAg) but your apps at the first.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question.

Answer (score 4):

Write pub gameimax. For any developer, enter pub and then the developer name. For example if you wanted to search up gamevil's apps, you would type in pub gamevil.

Comment: how a correct answer got a negative point? Your answer is correct ie pub:developername

Answer (score 1):

`gameimax` keyword contains `game` word. So it is possible it searches all the result for `game` also.

I have no references only experience. It's a style of SEO so there is no actual documentation.

Just go through [developer website](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/about/visibility.html).

From my experience it goes on:

- Title
- Relevant keywords in your description
- Amount of downloads
- Speed of downloads vs release date
- Star rating

  [This](http://droid-blog.net/2012/03/07/app-store-optimization-aso-45-ratings-installs-or-the-google-play-search-algorithm/) is also a very good artical about Google Play Store Search.

***EDIT :***

developer name also play roles in search. Change your developer name to unique.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If any more suggestion then please share, because it's harming our app downloads.

Comment: @TrishaThomas Please read article which i give you. Its describe in depth.

Comment: @Prince: I use a very unique developer name yet competitor apps do appear whenever I search for my name.
It must be a problem with Google.

Answer (score 0):

This problem happens whenever I update my apps on weekends and it lasts for the following 3 weeks.

When I update during week days, this problem never happens.

I use a very unique developer name. So I can assure you that it has nothing to do with your developer name.